# BAD FIELD ERROR in WHERE DATE CLAUSE for MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, where-clause, between

Why am I getting an error with the following code:

```
SELECT
Hour, 
SUM( CASE col WHEN '1' THEN data ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Sun', 
SUM( CASE col WHEN '2' THEN data ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Mon', 
SUM( CASE col WHEN '3' THEN data ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Tues', 
SUM( CASE col WHEN '4' THEN data ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Wed',     
SUM( CASE col WHEN '5' THEN data ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Thur',     
SUM( CASE col WHEN '6' THEN data ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Fri',     
SUM( CASE col WHEN '7' THEN data ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Sat'
FROM    (
        SELECT
            HOUR(arrPurch.PurchaseDate) as HOUR,
            DAYOFWEEK(arrPurch.PurchaseDate) as col,
            SUM(ROUND(arrPurch.Credits * 1.85 + arrPurch.Price,0)) AS Data
        FROM praisecharts_main_new.arrangementPurchases AS arrPurch
        INNER JOIN praisecharts_main_new.catalog_dev_arrangements 
            AS catDEVarr ON arrPurch.ArrangementID = catDEVarr.ArrangementID
        INNER JOIN praisecharts_main_new.members 
            ON arrPurch.MemberID = members.MemberID
        GROUP BY HOUR(arrPurch.PurchaseDate), DAYOFWEEK(arrPurch.PurchaseDate)
        ) AS stats 
WHERE 
    Hour BETWEEN 0 AND 23 
    --      AND arrPurch.PurchaseDate BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 29 DAY) 
    --      AND (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    --      AND arrPurch.PurchaseDate > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY Hour WITH ROLLUP
```

When I don't try to PIVOT the results with the CASE clauses, I don't get an error.  Here is an example of a query that works:

```
SELECT
DAYOFWEEK(arrPurch.PurchaseDate) AS DayWeek,
FORMAT(SUM(arrPurch.Credits*1.85+arrPurch.Price)/4,0) AS `c.Rev`
FROM
    praisecharts_main_new.arrangementPurchases AS arrPurch
INNER JOIN praisecharts_main_new.catalog_dev_arrangements AS catDEVarr ON 
    arrPurch.ArrangementID = catDEVarr.ArrangementID
INNER JOIN praisecharts_main_new.members 
    ON arrPurch.MemberID = members.MemberID
WHERE arrPurch.PurchaseDate BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 29 DAY) 
    AND (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY DayWeek WITH ROLLUP;
LIMIT 14
```

Comment: It might help to include the error message in your question.

Comment: Check your statement, you define the column as `Data` but are looking for `data` in your case statement.

Comment: I tried changing `Data` to `data`, but that didn't work.  When I expose any kind of DATE RANGE in the WHERE clause, I get this error: `ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'arrPurch.PurchaseDate' in 'where clause'`. I don't understand why I can put that exact DATE clause in other queries, but in this one, it creates an error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer. I moved the WHERE clause up to the embedded SELECT cause above, rather than at the bottom.  Here is an example of the code that works.

```
SELECT
Hour, 
SUM( CASE col WHEN '1' THEN data ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Sun', 
SUM( CASE col WHEN '2' THEN data ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Mon', 
SUM( CASE col WHEN '3' THEN data ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Tues', 
SUM( CASE col WHEN '4' THEN data ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Wed',     
SUM( CASE col WHEN '5' THEN data ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Thur',     
SUM( CASE col WHEN '6' THEN data ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Fri',     
SUM( CASE col WHEN '7' THEN data ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Sat'
FROM    (
        SELECT
            HOUR(arrPurch.PurchaseDate) as HOUR,
            DAYOFWEEK(arrPurch.PurchaseDate) as col,
            SUM(ROUND((arrPurch.Credits * 1.85 + arrPurch.Price)/4,0)) AS data
        FROM praisecharts_main_new.arrangementPurchases AS arrPurch
        INNER JOIN praisecharts_main_new.catalog_dev_arrangements 
            AS catDEVarr ON arrPurch.ArrangementID = catDEVarr.ArrangementID
        INNER JOIN praisecharts_main_new.members 
            ON arrPurch.MemberID = members.MemberID

        WHERE arrPurch.PurchaseDate BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 29 DAY) 
             AND (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)

        GROUP BY HOUR(arrPurch.PurchaseDate), 
            DAYOFWEEK(arrPurch.PurchaseDate)
    ) AS stats 
WHERE 
    Hour BETWEEN 0 AND 23 
GROUP BY Hour WITH ROLLUP
```